# Mongodb how to aggregate more different fields of the same collection with the same request?

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb, express

another shock with express and mongodb, I would like to aggregate more different fields of the same collection with the same request called aggregate4, together with another request called query (query is full text) (aggregate is regex) but I'm having difficulty, example:

```
collection.aggregate([{$match:{
                                                
$text: {$search: '\"' + query.split(' ').join('\" \"') + '\"'}, //full text req.query
                                                            
name_lower: new RegExp('^'+ aggregate1), // req.query.aggregate1 ok
surname_lower: new RegExp('^'+ aggregate2),//req.query.aggregate2 ok
sex_lower: new RegExp( aggregate3),//req.query.aggregate3 ok
                                    
$or:[{                                     
note4_lower: new RegExp(aggregate4), //problem //req.query.aggregate4 
note5_lower: new RegExp(aggregate4),//problem //req.query.aggregate4 
    }]
}]).limit(myLimit)
.toArray(function.......
```

note that note4_lower and note5_lower share the same request (aggregate4), unfortunately I only receive the note4.lower column in this case or note5.lower reversing the or and.

I tried to do the same with two $OR one for note4_lower and one for note5.lower, I also tried with collection.find as well as aggregate but nothing, or I receive only the "COLUMN" note4.lower or only the "COLUMN" note5.lower ... In both columns there are NULL fields (so either the field has note4.lower or note5.lower)

can someone help me?
I hope I explained myself well, thanks!

Comment: its safe to assume you don't make the bed every morning...

Comment: Did the comment refer to the question?